# why does `cat` append a space when displaying multiple strings?

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following vector:

```
output <- c("foo\n", "bar\n")
```

If I want to display this via `cat`, I get a weird indentation:

```
> cat(output)
foo
 bar
```

Why is there a space before "`bar`"? I can get around it with `paste`:

```
> cat(paste(output, collapse = ""))
foo
bar
```

but I don't understand why `cat` is behaving in this fashion in the first place? Is this a bug, or am I missing something about how `cat` behaves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cat` has a `sep` argument.

From `?cat`:

> `sep`: a character vector of strings to append after each element.

`sep` defaults to `" "`.

Hence:

```
output = c("foo\n", "bar\n")
cat(output, sep = "")
foo
bar
```